# Android ormlite foregin object doesn't get saved

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

I'm retrieving data from a `Json`, deserializing with `Gson` and saving into a database with `ORMLite`. After querying the foreign object, the result is 0.

I'm fetching the data through API (network):

```
[{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "California",
    "desc": "",
    "coords": {
        "lat": 37.755363,
        "lon": -122.478676
    }
}, {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Texas",
    "desc": "asd",
    "coords": {
        "lat": 29.739861,
        "lon": -95.395660
    }
}]
```

Building the objects with `Gson`:

```
List<Location> locations = new Gson().fromJson(szData, Location.class);
```

I have checked with Android Studio debug, the objects were created successfully.

Saving the locations into the database:

```
Dao<Location, Long> dao = dbHelper.getDaoLocation();
long entries = dao.create(locations);
```

The objects were saved successfully to the database.

Getting the locations from the database via `ORMLite`:

```
List<Location> locations = daoLocation.queryBuilder().query();
```

As expected, I'm getting the results from the database. However, the Location's Coordinate is empty. It's because I haven't called `dao.refresh()` on the `Coordinate` object.

The models:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Locations")
public class Location {
   @DatabaseField(columnName = "id", generatedId = true)
   private transient long id;

   @DatabaseField(columnName = "server_id")
   @SerializedName("id")
   private long serverId;

   private String name;
   private String desc;

   @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
   private Coordinate coords;

   // Getters and setters
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Coordinates")
public class Coordinate {
   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
   private long id;

   @SerializedName("lat")
   private double latitude;
   @SerializedName("lon")
   private double longitude;

   // Getters and setters
}
```

As you can see, I don't have a reference to the Location object from the Coordinate.

If I query the Coordinate table (for debug purpose), I'm getting 0 result.

```
Dao<Coordinate, Long> dao = dbHelper.getDaoCoordinate();
QueryBuilder<Coordinate, Long> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
List<Coordinate> coordinates = qb.query();
```

The above query gives me 0 results. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the names of the Classes and the name of the foreign object.

I have changed the name of the foreign object to match the table's name:

**Locations class (same)**:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true)
private Coordinate coords;
```

**Coordinate class (new)**:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "coords")
public class Coordinate {
```